# Bootstrap md col overwritten by lg col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

Trying to better set up a large form I have by utilising bootstraps `col` sizes (`xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`) but for some reason all the columns switch to the large a lot earlier than they are supposed to. i.e. `xs` goes to `sm` at around 615px instead of 768. `sm` to `md` around 800px instead of 992px and `md` to `lg` around 960px instead of 1200px.

I'm using `react-bootstrap v0.31.0` ([link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#grid))

The screen width in this image 968px. I've been testing in chrome in developer mode with screen size under the 'responsive' part. 
[image: Lg overriding md.]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or might need to change?

Section of HTML:

```
    <div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
            <label for="FirstName" class="col-xs-12 control-label"><strong>*</strong>
                <!-- react-text: 1261 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 1262 -->First Name:
                <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="FirstName" value="John" id="FirstName" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <!-- react-empty: 1266 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
            <label for="MiddleName" class="col-xs-12 control-label">
                <!-- react-text: 1270 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 1271 -->Middle Name or initial:
                <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Middle Name or Initial" name="MiddleName" value="W" id="MiddleName" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <!-- react-empty: 1275 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
            <label for="LastName" class="col-xs-12 control-label"><strong>*</strong>
                <!-- react-text: 1280 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 1281 -->Last Name:
                <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="LastName" value="Doe" id="LastName" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <!-- react-empty: 1285 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
            <label for="FormerName" class="col-xs-12 control-label">
                <!-- react-text: 1289 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 1290 -->Former Name:
                <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Former Name" name="FormerName" value="" id="FormerName" class="form-control" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                <!-- react-empty: 1294 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
            <label for="Gender" class="col-xs-12 control-label">
                <!-- react-text: 1298 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 1299 -->Gender:
                <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="Select Select--single is-clearable is-searchable has-value">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Gender" value="Male">
                    <div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value"><div class="Select-value"><span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-5--value-item">Male</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" value="" style="width: 5px; box-sizing: content-box;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre;"></div>
                    </div>
                    </span><span class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value" aria-label="Clear value"><span class="Select-clear">×</span></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- react-empty: 1313 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback">
        <label for="Dob" class="col-xs-12 control-label"><strong>*</strong>
            <!-- react-text: 1318 -->
            <!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 1319 -->Date of Birth:
            <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa fa-lg fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
                <input type="text" id="Dob" name="Dob" placeholder="Enter date of birth" class="form-control" value="10011987">
            </div>
            <!-- react-empty: 1324 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be useful to see what your HTML output looked like.  Not much we can do with this screenshot but nod and say "Yes, it does seem like `.col-lg-2` is being applied here.  We can't really troubleshoot was to *why*

Comment: Sorry bout that, I added an HTML snippet

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late. But check are you viewing your website in 100% view. It makes me forget about that.
With: ctrl + (+/-) you can adjust view, or in Chrome browser you have magnifier icon.
[image]